# How to generate the borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My question is the following:

> Is the borel sigma algebra (field) $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ generated by the set $$\mathcal{A} :=\{E_1 \times E_2 \times \cdots \times E_n : E_1 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), ...,E_n\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}?$$
>   In other words, if $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ denotes the sigma field generated by $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e. the smallest sigma field containing $\mathcal{A}$). Is then $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? And if so, how can I prove (or see) that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes: this is because every open set is generated by countably many multi-intervals.

Comment: In order to answer this question it would be helpful to know how you defined $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$...

Comment: Did you know that you can approximate open sets in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ using small cuboids? Did you know you can create small cuboids by taking products of intervals over $\mathbb{R}$?